# jsfiddle save functionality

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to make a save functionality like the one on jsfiddle. But i don't really know how to do it. So i have stored some data on a mysql database and used `history.pushState` to put a key in the url bar:

```
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  
    var string_length = 5;                     
    var num_chars = chars.length;              
    var result = '';                     

    while(string_length--) {   
        result += chars[ Math.floor( Math.random() * num_chars ) ];  
    }


    history.pushState('', '', result);
```

I am using jquery, ajax, php to insert data into the database. The "result" is stored as a ID in the database. How do i use that to get the right data from the database. How do i make that url shareable to others?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui You need to stop telling people to "check your answer". Scrolling down the page will allow them to do that anyway...

Comment: @Bojangles , OK! Next time I will take care of it!

Answer (score 2):

Give the URL with an ID in it, like this (for example)...

```
http://yoursite.com?pageid=1234
```

and then in PHP you can access it like this...

```
$pageid = $_GET["pageid"];
```

You can then use that value to get data from your MySQL database as required.

Comment: Now I understood! +1 for telling me what the OP's asking! :)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui No worries :)

Comment: The id string is made in javascript. How do i pass that id string over to the php part so i can match it to the database?